# Grouped histograms using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, histogram

I have a dataset such as the one below:

```
Re  Years       Human       Natural     Total
AP  19711973    6.210389863 0           6.210389863
AP  19741976    5.670355962 0.270016951 5.940372912
AP  19771979    5.670355962 1.080067802 6.750423764
BR  19711973    20.65502657 0.590143616 21.24517019
BR  19741976    37.76919145 1.770430849 39.5396223
BR  19771979    37.17904783 6.49157978  43.67062761
RV  19711973    19.8480084  0.700517943 20.54852634
RV  19741976    26.38617587 3.269083736 29.6552596
RV  19771979    16.34541868 3.736095698 20.08151438
```

I would like to create three separate histograms with the "Human" data (using the same limits for axes) based on each "Re" column. My code is below:

```
df1.hist(df1,column=df1['Human'],by=df1['Re'])
```

However, I receive this error:

```
TypeError: hist_frame() got multiple values for keyword argument 'column'
```

Not sure why this error is preventing things from being ran as there obviously should be multiple values in the column. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

- You don't need to pass `df1` to the `hist` method. You're using a method of the `df1` dataframe, it already knows to use `df1` as the data.
- You just pass the name of the column as a string, not the column itself

So the correct code is:

```
df1.hist(column='Human', by='Re')
```

Comment: Of course it was something that simple. I tried a bunch of different argument combinations but not that one. Thanks!